# spark remote develop environment

Tags: java, apache-spark

i want to remote spark develop environment.

A machine is my develop machine, java, eclipse, windows 10.

also i have another machine already installed cloduera(spark on yarn).

i tried this

```
    String appName = "test" + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String master = "spark://*:6066";
    String host = "*";
    String jar = "C:\\Users\\default.DESKTOP-0BP338U\\Desktop\\workspace\\workspace_study\\spark-start-on-yarn\\target\\spark-start-on-yarn-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar";

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
            .set("spark.driver.host",  host)
            .setJars(new String[]{jar});
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

but connection was refused.

how can i develop and test the spark program on my A machine?

---

i added environment variable

[image]

and this is my code

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString())
            .setMaster("yarn");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);


    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,4,1,1,1,4,2,2,4,1,1,3,4,2,3);
    JavaRDD<Integer> distData = sc.parallelize(data);

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> pairs = distData.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(s, 1));
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);

    System.out.println("================= " + counts);

    sc.close();
    sc.stop();
```

and error is "SparkException : Cloud not parse Master URL: 'yarn'"

what things i missed? please help me...

Comment: *spark on yarn*... Then why are you not setting the master to YARN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. Download your Hadoop cluster's `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` configuration files.
2. Set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` envrionment variable in **your** machine. Or, if that doesn't work, then you can place the XML files in your `src/main/resources` folder to include them on the classpath.
3. Use `setMaster("yarn-client")`

> Ensure that `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `YARN_CONF_DIR` points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster. These configs are used to write to HDFS and connect to the YARN ResourceManager)

[Spark on YARN](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

[Running Spark from an outside machine](http://clarkupdike.blogspot.com/2014/12/running-spark-on-yarn-from-outside.html)

4. Make an HDFS `/user` folder with your **local** username. This is needed for HDFS permissions.
5. Develop, and preferably use Maven/Gradle to manage your Java libraries. You also need to use the [Cloudera Maven repository for you respective Hadoop versions](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh5_maven_repo.html)

You don't need `setJars()` either. Your app should connect and run on it's own.

Comment: @circket_007 thanks. i set the environment variable HADOOP_CONF_DIR and YARN_CONF_DIR in my windows machine(for develop). what kind of yarn address:port in the setMaster("***") ??

Comment: It is not an address:port. It is literally `"yarn"`. Read the first link

Comment: Try `yarn-client`?

Comment: Also, only `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is needed, not it and `YARN_CONF_DIR`. The files you want are `yarn-site.xml`, `core-site.xml`, and `hdfs-site.xml` (plus `hive-site.xml`, if using Hive)

Comment: i tried to change .setMaster("yarn-client"). then met no executable ...... and set the winutils.exe. but console said "Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tired 0 times ........" 1~10 times again. so i tried to find localhost or 0.0.0.0 value in configurations, but i could't find.

Comment: `yarn.resourcemanager.address` defaults to that port... https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Comment: You've not configured or downloaded the correct XML files from your cluster (which you can get from Cloudera Manager)

Comment: i downloaded hadoop conf files in "/etc/hadoop/conf/*". i think my problem is eclipse doesn't load the configuration files from %HADOOP_CONF_DIR%.

Comment: It should. Otherwise, you'd get other errors. Please check the contents of the `yarn-site.xml` you downloaded vs the one on the cluster for `yarn.resourcemanager.address`

Comment: i checked all configuration files but still have error that resource manager is 0.0.0.0. so i tried that 'set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", "myresourcemanager")' and pass the resource manager connection but 'SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls enabled; users with view permissions: Set(*, default); users with modify permissions: Set(*, default)' error i met. so i am finding to add proxyuser 'default' using cloudera manager. but i don't think it is proper way.

Comment: i cant understand why eclipse cannot read the yarn configuration files in %HADOOP_CONF_DIR%. this variable is working. :(

Comment: You can try to add your hadoop files into `src/main/resources`. That'll put them in the classpath of your application.

Comment: you are right! it was passed resource manager connection and i met the hadoop permission error. i will follow step4. thank you very much. your are my first spark hero :):):):):)

Comment: Maybe `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is only used for `spark-submit`... Haven't actually tested any of this recently